# Webview not initializing

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When ever I try to use a web view it gives me a null pointer exception, my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

the Logs are:

02-18 22:08:06.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.web/com.test.web.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 22:08:06.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 22:08:06.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at com.test.web.Main.onCreate(Main.java:17)

(there where more logs just none of them pertained to the problem)

On a semi- related note how do you make code look like code on stackexchange?

So I'm guessing the webView isn't initializing correctly?

Comment: Can you pls show your main.xml file

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="@+id/webView"
    />
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting NullPointerException because in your main.xml file you have defined a TextView not a WebView.

Just change the TextView to WebView

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

         <WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: *Face Palm* need to pay more attention

Comment: @Narhem: you had got error in line number 17 , am i right, what is the code you typed on that line

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
if I comment it out it is the next line though webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
Which leads me to believe there is something wrong with webView

Comment: @Narhem: so the error is not on the line of webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); also pls ensure that you had defined WebChromeClient()

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh:there is no error on that line, and I just did.

Comment: @Narhem: i had found your problem, are you here?

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh: yes, sorry I fell asleep it was 2am where I live.
but the problem was always on         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);